# Benchmarking dotnet code using BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, benchmarking

BenchmarkDotNet git url is https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet.
i read a small article from here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BenchmarkingNETCode.aspx where scott said how to use BenchmarkDotNet lib.

scott mention

**The result is lovely output like this in a table you can even paste into a GitHub issue if you like.**

[image]

one thing is not clear where this lib will out the benchmark records ?

so my request is if anyone used it previously then please share knowledge like how to configure benchmark lib to benchmark output to console or image file ?

please share relevant information. thanks

Answer (score 2):

An exporter allows you to export results of your benchmark in different formats. By default, files with results will be located in `.\BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results`directory. Default exporters are: csv, html and markdown. For more information about exporters please visit the official web page of BenchmarkDotNet: http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Configs/Exporters.htm.